# Can I get a store name/restaurant name with mapkit?(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, mkannotation

I have a mapview and I added a method to drop a pin on the location where the user had pressed. The callout shows the address of the location as shown on the image.

[screenshot of my mapview with annotation pin and callout view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7aOD.jpg)

And my code is as following:

```
func onTapGestureRecognized(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    let location = tapRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    let getLat: CLLocationDegrees = coordinate.latitude
    let getLon: CLLocationDegrees = coordinate.longitude
    let theLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: getLat, longitude: getLon)

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(theLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]
        var theLocationName = ""
        var theStreetNumber = ""
        var theStreet = ""
        var theCity = ""
        var theZip = ""
        var theCountry = ""

        // Address dictionary
        print(placeMark.addressDictionary as Any)

        // Location name
        if let locationName = placeMark.name{
            theLocationName = locationName
        }

        if let streetNumber = placeMark.subThoroughfare{
            theStreetNumber = streetNumber
        }
        // Street address
        if let street = placeMark.thoroughfare {
            theStreet = street
        }

        // City
        if let city = placeMark.locality {
            theCity = city
        }

        // Zip code
        if let zip = placeMark.postalCode{
            theZip = zip
        }

        // Country
        if let country = placeMark.isoCountryCode{
            theCountry = country
        }

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = theLocationName
        annotation.subtitle = theStreetNumber + " " + theStreet + ", " + theCity + ", " + theCountry + ", " + theZip
        if let location = placeMark.location {
            annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
            // Display the annotation
            self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
        }
    })

}
```

As you can see, when I try to get the location name by calling the line (((( if let locationName = placeMark.name )))), I can only get the address: "5197 Yonge St", instead of the restaurant name : " Pho 88 Restaurant ".

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? or is it simply cannot be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because a **map** location is just that? Not a **business** location?

Comment: Your code works perfectly with some other location, try for a different location.

Comment: @ArpitDongre Yeah I have tried with other locations, it sometimes shows the name of a place or a plaza (i.e. City Centre North York, Mel Eastman Square), but never a restaurant name or a store name(business names)

Comment: @dfd, hmm if that's the reason, do you know how I can get a business location?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete answer, but I may be able to point you in the right direction.  As far as I can see, you will only ever get a single entry returned for `placemarks`, but you **can** get a more complete list using `MKLocalSearchRequest`.  the challenge is going to be how you match up the returned values to exactly which one you want - maybe you have to ask the user to select from a short list?  Also, I think you need to specify which type of establishment you're searching for.  Here's something you could include within your completion handler above

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurant"  // or whatever you're searching for
request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: getLat, longitude: getLon), span: self.mapView.region.span)

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
                return
    }
    print("There are \(response.mapItems.count)")
    for item in response.mapItems {
        // You may be able to match the address to what the geoCode gives you
        // or present the user with a list of options 
        print("\(item.name), \(item.placemark)")
    }
}
```

When I was testing this, the addresses didn't always match up, even when zoomed in - so that `geoCoder` might give me `1-3 Some Street` while the `MKLocalSearchRequest` returned a restaurant at `3 Some Street`